Air intake sizing for a Turbojet Engine
I am trying to design a UAV with a turbojet engine. The turbojet engine is already selected, and I want to calculate how big the air intake will need to be for this engine.
I have read that the size depends on the mass flow rate, Mach number of the flow and design Mach number of the engine, and the intake size is such that the flow speed can be reduced accordingly.
Is there a way to estimate the air intake size (area of the air intake front face)?

What's the engine? What else has it been installed in?

@RalphJ The engine is AL-PBS-350, it is for use on UAVs, UCAVs : https://www.pbs.cz/en/Products/Aerospace/Aircraft-Engines/Jet-engine-AI-PBS-350

Inflow mass = outflow mass?  Cruise would need less air in.  Some type of adjustable ramp could save drag.

Crosthwait, E. L., Kennon, I. G., and Roland, H. L., "Preliminary Design Methodology for Air -Induction Systems," Technical Report SEG-TR-67-1, Wright-Patterson AFB, OH, Jan. 1967 is, I've read, highly reccomended.

I would defer to asking the manufacturer of the engine. What do THEY recommend? At least as a starting point. And that engine is pretty beefy - 51kg. You're designing a relatively LARGE UAV.
